# Why does sleeping before a write slow down the subsequent write?

Tags: python, performance, go, scheduler

I'm seeing occasionally slow performance in writing to a file (or socket) and in debugging, I ended up with a small test harness to reproduce it. I'm seeing strange behavior whereby the longer I sleep in between writes, the longer the write itself takes. I reproduced the test harness in both Go and Python and see similar results in both. I also see similar results on both my mac and linux machines.

The key confusion is that the timing code in both cases looks like

```
sleep(x)
startTime = now()
write(msg)
endTime = now()
writeTime = endTime - startTime
```

where `writeTime` gets significantly longer as the `sleep` increases, despite the sleep not being included in the timing at all!

Python:

```py
import time

f = open("/dev/null", "w")

msg = "0" * 1024


for sleepMicros in [0, 1, 10, 100, 1000]:
    totalSendTime = 0
    cntOver10us = 0
    for _ in range(10000):
        time.sleep(sleepMicros / 1000 / 1000)
        startSendTime = time.time()
        f.write(msg)
        sentTime = time.time()

        timeInSend = sentTime - startSendTime
        totalSendTime += timeInSend
        if timeInSend > 10 / 1000 / 1000:
            cntOver10us += 1

    print(f"sleep: {sleepMicros}us\tTotal time in send: {totalSendTime * 1000}ms\tCount over 10us: {cntOver10us}")
```

Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("/dev/null")

    msg := make([]byte, 1024)

    for _, sleepMicros := range []time.Duration{0, 1, 10, 100, 1000} {
        totalSendTime := time.Duration(0)
        cntOver10us := 0
        sleepDuration := sleepMicros * time.Microsecond
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            time.Sleep(sleepDuration)
            startSendTime := time.Now()
            _, err := f.Write(msg)
            sentTime := time.Now()

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("SendMessage got error", err)
            }
            timeInSend := sentTime.Sub(startSendTime)
            totalSendTime += timeInSend
            if timeInSend > 10*time.Microsecond {
                cntOver10us++
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("sleep:", sleepDuration, "\tTotal time in send:", totalSendTime, "\tCount over 10us:", cntOver10us)
    }
}
```

Results:

Python:

```
(venv) % python write_to_devnull_mini.py
sleep: 0us  Total time in send: 2.109527587890625ms Count over 10us: 0
sleep: 1us  Total time in send: 1.9390583038330078ms    Count over 10us: 0
sleep: 10us Total time in send: 1.9574165344238281ms    Count over 10us: 0
sleep: 100us    Total time in send: 5.476236343383789ms Count over 10us: 9
sleep: 1000us   Total time in send: 50.98319053649902ms Count over 10us: 1179
```

Go:

```
(venv) % go run write_to_devnull_mini.go
sleep: 0s   Total time in send: 5.724469ms  Count over 10us: 0
sleep: 1µs  Total time in send: 6.404582ms  Count over 10us: 1
sleep: 10µs     Total time in send: 4.346918ms  Count over 10us: 0
sleep: 100µs    Total time in send: 10.909356ms     Count over 10us: 8
sleep: 1ms  Total time in send: 112.627213ms    Count over 10us: 1307
```

My best guess is that this is some artifact of the scheduler, but would love to understand what's happening. How does sleeping for 1ms in between writes cause the total time spent between calls to `time.Now()` to go up by 20x, and the number of "slow" (>10us) writes to increase 200-fold?

Comment: What is significant about 10 microseconds?

Comment: Nothing significant at 10us, I just wanted to understand whether there were a large number of slow writes or individual extremely slow ones, and it ended up being a value that almost never happened at the shorter sleep times and happened very frequently at the larger sleep times.

Comment: Devices likes SSDs can enter in sleeping mode when unused and take more time to wake up then. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908947/writing-a-small-file-blocks-for-20-ms/73013307#73013307) for more information about this. Additionally, the scheduler is free to wait for a bigger time than the one requested. This typically happens for small waiting times and when other processes are running (especially with a higher priority and the waiting time is smaller than a quantum).

Comment: I think the filesystem / SSD shouldn't enter into it since I'm hitting /dev/null in this case. I know the scheduler can wait longer, but in this case, the sleep time isn't being included in the timing at all, so the confusion comes down to how the longer sleep can sneak into affecting the later write.

Comment: Invert your loop. That is,instead of `{0, 1, 10, 100, 1000}`, do `{1000, 100, 10, 1, 0}` in that order. What do you see now?

Comment: Writes go to the file system cache and are sent to the output device in the background. You could be seeing the affect. I reversed the numbers and got very different times.

Comment: Good question, @selbie! I see the same thing reversed
total time spent for python: `58, 8, 2, 2, 2` and go `84, 12, 4, 4, 3`

Answer (score 1):

Wait - this looks suspicious:

```
totalSendTime := time.Duration(0)
cntOver10us := 0
for _, sleepMicros := range []time.Duration{0, 1, 10, 100, 1000} {
    sleepDuration := sleepMicros * time.Microsecond
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        ...
    }
    fmt.Println("sleep:", sleepDuration, "\tTotal time in send:", totalSendTime, "\tCount over 10us:", cntOver10us)
}
```

Don't you really want to reset totalSendTime and cntOver10us on each iteration? Otherwise, totalSleep and cntOver10us is going to keep going up no matter how long you sleep.

```
for _, sleepMicros := range []time.Duration{0, 1, 10, 100, 1000} {
    totalSendTime := time.Duration(0)
    cntOver10us := 0
    sleepDuration := sleepMicros * time.Microsecond
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        ...
    }
    fmt.Println("sleep:", sleepDuration, "\tTotal time in send:", totalSendTime, "\tCount over 10us:", cntOver10us)
}
```

Otherwise, your totalSendTime for each outer loop is only going to go up since you never seem to reset it

Comment: oh goodness you're totally right, let me fix this up

Comment: Fixed now, and still showing the timing artifacts (I had originally tested this without the outer loop, simply re-running the whole thing, so I knew the effect was "real", but totally botched moving it into a single reproduction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You omitted details like core count, scheduler, and loading from other processes.

It could be that frequent sleeping is reducing your dynamic priority.
That's different from the user-set `nice` value.
Your process is predicted to use only a few cycles per second,
so it's OK to pre-empt the cPython bytecode interpreter
with a higher priority process that has a tighter deadline.

But it could also be that frequent long sleeps are allowing
other processes to dirty the cache so you suffer more cache misses.
Or, similarly, you lack affinity and keep getting rescheduled
on different cores.
Instrument the cache, or look at PSR reported by `ps`
if you want to investigate that.

A simple thing to look at would be

```
import resource
...
r = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
```

and note patterns in how voluntary and `r.ru_nivcsw` involuntary
context switches increment.
Also, verify that `r.ru_minflt` remains constant.

Hmmm, come to think of it, slowness due to L3 cache miss
should show up as non-constant user and sys mode deltas
reported by [getrusage()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource-usage).

Comment: Thank you! This is a good lead.

`ru_minflt` indeed stays constant

Other patterns
`ru_nvcsw` increases by 10k each loop, presumably one per write, `ru_nivcsw` goes `141, 141, 176, 181, 580` across runs, so maybe something there

Almost all of the `ru_stime` and `ru_utime` is spent in the final loop (both .1 out of .15 total)

Comment: Understanding how they behave in aggregate is fine. I was suggesting to look at the _distribution_ on individual readings, similar to how you used `cntOver10us` to get a feel for the shape of a related distribution. A brute force approach would be to append each delta to a list or text file, then at the end sort values for extremes, or plot a histogram.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Ok, yes, I have a run where I call getrusage before the startSendTime and after the sentTime on each loop, and then look at the cases where `timeInSend > 10us`

It doesn't look correlated at all to `nvcsw` or `nivcsw`, but the maybe interesting, and maybe surprising to me thing is that almost all of the time in the slow loops is utime, not stime